# HMAC SHA256 Powershell convert

Tags: powershell, sha256, hmac

Why does the following powershell script:

```
$privateKey = "843c1f887b"
$requestData = "1543448572|d.lastname@firm.com|Firstname Lastname"
function signRequest {
    $hmacsha = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256
    $hmacsha.key = [Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($privateKey)
    $signature = $hmacsha.ComputeHash([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($requestData))
    $signature = [Convert]::ToBase64String($signature)
    $outi = $signature
    return $signature
}
```

convert to hash:

```
FipK51tOtzb2m2yFQAf5IK6BNthClnqE24luMzYMPuo=
```

and other online hmac sha256 generators with the same input to:

```
162a4ae75b4eb736f69b6c854007f920ae8136d842967a84db896e33360c3eea
```

any suggestions what I'm doing wrong in the script?
Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code produces the correct HMAC, you're just base64-encoding it instead of output a hex string like all the other tools.

Change this line

```
$signature = [Convert]::ToBase64String($signature)
```

to

```
$signature = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($signature).Replace('-','').ToLower()
```

Explanation:

- [`[BitConverter]::ToString($signature)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.tostring#System_BitConverter_ToString_System_Byte___) produces a hexadecimal string (`16-2A-4A-E7...`)
- [`String.Replace('-','')`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace#System_String_Replace_System_String_System_String_) removes the `-` (`162A4AE7...`)
- [`String.ToLower()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.tolower#System_String_ToLower) lowercases the final string (`162a4ae7...`)